# how can i achieve 10000 tps in layer zero polkadot based chain

Tags: polkadot, transactions, blockchain

I have my blockchain deployed on production . i  want some addition in my chain. i want my chain to have 10000 tps .How can i achieve that in my current layer0 chain without using multiple parachains .

Comment: Users can batch their transactions, even 10000 in one by using `Utility::Batch`.

Comment: Please better explain the situation and the environment in which you are working, considering that those who want to answer don't know _anything_ about your chain and requirements. Given the data that you have given so far, I can create a remark chain with substrate that can probably support a very large tps.

Comment: @kianenigma i have  my layer 0 blockchain build on polkadot -.9.36 version .i have came through a condition in which i want 10000 tps . i want to know about  the methods through  which i can achieve this in my layer 0 chain . 
Utility batch method will not be feasible in my case 
and i cannot add multiple parachains in this.